# What keyboard command can be used to move the cursor to the end of the next word on the Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, switching

In Windows and Ubuntu one can move the cursor to the end of the next word in text by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>.

What's the equivalent of this on the Mac?

Comment: Command+left and Command+right brings you to the end or beginning of a line - something that I find really useful as well.

Comment: ...something accomplished with Home and End on PCs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd>

Comment: ... and why is it not listed in keyboard shortcuts ...

Comment: @GEdgar Gremlings.

Comment: it's a global thing like the enter or shift keys… goes without saying

Comment: it doesn't "go without saying" since it had to be said. I too wanted to know this.

Comment: Weird/relevant: on older version of Microsoft Word, it used to be command instead of option. Took them _forever_ to get in line with the rest of Mac OS.

Comment: If you're using windows keyboard Alt + Left/Right

Comment: @mahemadhi The question has the answer for windows.

Comment: @KitSunde I am using windows keyboard with Mac OSX. So to be precise its alt key

Answer (score 1):

This is a late return from an outlying precinct on this question, but on my 2014 MacBook Pro using Word 2011, I stumbled on to how to move to the beginning and the end using 
"fn" + option + Left arrow, and Rt arrow respectively.

These combinations also work for the Word for Mac Preview v 15.8.

Answer (score -1):

It's really quite simple: just us <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>left</kbd>.

Comment: That somehow contradicts the already accepted answer